# I need a mod_rewrite expression to rewrite all paths that do not have a file extension

Tags: php, regex, linux, apache, mod-rewrite

What i'm trying to do is have my main script index.php process all requests that do not contain a file extension. All other requests that do contain a file extension such as images should not be affected by mod_rewrite.

For example, I need the following urls to all be rewritten to /index.php?req={REQUEST_URI}:
/index/a/b/c
/index/a/b
/index

But disregard urls with an extension. Apache and not PHP should process urls such as:
/index/a/test.png
/index/a/b/c/script.js

My current expression only works for paths with a single directory.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?req=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

This expression rewrites "/index", but not "/index/a" and so on...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule !^/.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]){2,}$ /index.php?req=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

This redirects anything that does **not** match the pattern `^/.*\.([a-zA-Z0-9]){2,}$`. The pattern defines a string ending with a period `\.` followed by two or more alphanumeric characters `([a-zA-Z0-9]){2,}`.

If you know the length of your file extensions, you can modify the numbers in the curly braces; e.g. file extensions between 1 and 3 characters would be satisfied with `([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,3}`